# TKinter text box "insert" optimization

Tags: python, performance, tkinter, optimization, textbox

2 issues :

- Main issue - deleting and inserting instead **tagged** lines (> 100K lines)
  How can i optimize speed ?
  (I am deleting specific line, then i insert the tagged line at same place)
- inserting ~3 million lines (single string, multi line) - takes ~1 second -
  I can live with that, but if there is a better way, would like to hear.

I am using Cython, improved performance a lot for string manipulations before textbox insertion.
Can i use Cython to insert to Tkinter textbox faster ? (Probably not)

Would appreciate a professional that took the time to investigate this type of optimization.

**Added Code:**

#Inserting all lines, quick when doing in a single call

self.textWindow.insert(END, buffer)

Putting tagged lines instead of current line:

for Lines in buffer:  # Around 3 millions iterations

```
self.textWindow.delete(f'{Lines[i]}.0', f'{Lines[i]}.end+1c')
self.textWindow.insert(f'{Lines[i]}.0', Lines[i], tag[i])
```

is there a direct API i can put all tag lines in a single call ? (Even in Tkl/C) ?

Tried with:

```
self.textWindow.tag_add(tag[i], f'{Lines[i]}.0', f'{Lines[i]}.end')
```

No color changed in this way **

Even if this works, it will not be fast enough, that's why i want to find a more creative way to optimize time to execute.

Regards,
Amit

Comment: 3 million lines in approximately 1 second sounds brilliant. Many off the shelf text editors would struggle with loading 3 million lines. Maybe you could only load the X lines that are visible in the text box then when the user scrolls, load the next section line by line.

Comment: Yes, looks like this "Editor" is working pretty fast.
But the issue is that when you need to highlight some of the lines, the act of "delete" and "insert" for >100000 is ~3 seconds ("Delete" --> "Insert" Tkinter API action per line)
Need a better way.
Plus, loading part without stalling screen means another thread, which by itself has a pretty hectic overhead, that in Python is just not worth it.

Comment: You shouldn't need to delete and then reinsert. You can apply tags to an existing range of text.

Comment: Tried with tag_add(tag, line.col, line.end) to existing line. no tag color for the line.
with insert color is good.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Added sample code